# avoid memory errors with AVX intinsics

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, intrinsics, avx

I've been trying to speed up some neural network computations using AVX instructions. However, I keep running into the following error "Unhandled exception at [...]: Access violation reading location [...]".

I tried to isolate the issue but as the memory seems to be corrupted somewhere, the error doesn't show up at the same place each time, and i suspect it be misleading. Does anyone know what might cause the issue?

Here is some reproducible code:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

inline const int num_avx_registers = 16;
inline const int floats_per_reg = 4;

inline const int HKP_size = 100;
inline constexpr int acc_size = 256;

class NNLayer {
    public:
    alignas(32) float* weight;
    alignas(32) float* bias;

    NNLayer(){
        weight = new float[HKP_size * acc_size]; // flattened 2D array.
        bias = new float[acc_size];


        // initialize the weights and bias with test values
        for (uint32_t i=0; i<HKP_size * acc_size; i++){
            weight[i] = 1.F;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<acc_size; i++){
            bias[i] = static_cast<float>(i);
        }
    }

    ~NNLayer(){
        delete[] weight;
        delete[] bias;
    }
};

class Accumulator {
    public:
    alignas(32) std::array<float, acc_size> accumulator_w;
    alignas(32) std::array<float, acc_size> accumulator_b;

    std::array<float, acc_size>& Accumulator::operator[](bool color){
        return color ? accumulator_w : accumulator_b;
    }
};

class NNUE {
    public:
    Accumulator accumulator;
    NNLayer first_layer = NNLayer();

    void compute_accumulator(const std::vector<int> active_features, bool color){
        // we have 256 floats to process.
        // there are 16 avx registers, and each can hold 4 floats.
        // therefore we need to do 256/64 = 4 passes to the registers.

        constexpr int c_size = num_avx_registers * floats_per_reg; //chunk size
        constexpr int num_chunks = acc_size / c_size;
        
        static_assert(acc_size % c_size == 0);

        __m256 avx_regs[num_avx_registers];

        // we process 1/4th of the whole data at each loop.
        // we add c_idx to the indexes pick up where we left off at the last chunk.
        for (int c_idx = 0; c_idx < num_chunks*c_size; c_idx += c_size){ // chunk index

            // load the bias from memory
            for (int i = 0; i < num_avx_registers; i++){
                avx_regs[i] = _mm256_load_ps(&first_layer.bias[c_idx + i*floats_per_reg]);
            }

            // add the active weights
            for (const int &a: active_features){
                for (int i = 0; i < num_avx_registers; i++){
                    // a*acc_size is to get the a-th row of the flattened 2D array.
                    avx_regs[i] = _mm256_add_ps(
                        avx_regs[i],
                        _mm256_load_ps(&first_layer.weight[a*acc_size + c_idx + i*floats_per_reg])
                        );
                }
            }

            //store the result in the accumulator
            for (int i = 0; i < num_avx_registers; i++){
                _mm256_store_ps(&accumulator[color][c_idx + i*floats_per_reg], avx_regs[i]);
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    NNUE nnue;

    std::vector<int> act_f = {2, 1, 70, 62};
    nnue.compute_accumulator(act_f, true);

    std::cout << "still alive\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shaggy lyrics aside, if I were to cast a vote on this question, it'd be a downvote. The error message you received should make getting a stack trace in a debugger pretty straightforward. But you didn't even bother with that. I would assume that someone messing about with ML knows how to use a debugger. But I suppose that clashes with the trope that data scientists are notoriously horrible programmers.

Comment: Well as you guessed i am new to c++ and programming in general. However i _did_ bother with the debugger. If you can find the issue easily good for you but i tried for hours yesterday without sucess. Also, i am not a data scientist

Comment: Then where's the debugging information? That kind of crash should be traceable. New to C++ *and* programming also tells me that a neural net is not a great starter project. As for me finding the error in your [mre] might take a bit as it [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/M4rxcqPvd).

Comment: [Once I got it to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/ETs369T8T), I can see a stack trace. From the stack trace `#1 0x401b2f in NNUE::compute_accumulator(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, bool) /app/example.cpp:73` is the problematic line. From which iteration of the loop, I couldn't say as this was what I was able to get on godbolt, and I'm not going to run it locally with my debugger.

Comment: There is no trace. The program simply runs and stops without printing anything. the unhandled exception i found was from the debugger, and on the line where i use `_mm256_add_ps`. As for the compilation, it compiles on my computer, but i use msvc.

Comment: Just because it doesn't float one automatically doesn't mean there is no trace. I don't use msvc, so I don't know what flags I need to achieve the result I got with g++. But you're likely in VS, set a breakpoint in that loop.

Comment: the issue was that avx registers can hold 8 floats, not 4. Changing this made everything work. Thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: Highlight the line with `_mm256_add_ps` n the question, that's an important detail. Apparently you are debugging from IDE, so Debug->Windows->Disassembly or Alt-8 should get you into disassembly, where you can show the instructions, also you can look up operand values.

Comment: mm256 intrinsics indeed use 8 floats so floats_per_reg should be 8. But your example code also has 620 as an index into an array of 100 items (acc_size long each).

Comment: alex guteniev Sure, but i've just started learning assembly, so i'll need some time before I can use it to debug. Andrey Turkin you are right. I edited the question as this wasn't the issue, just an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 6):

`alignas(32) float* weight;` only aligns the address where the pointer is stored, not the pointed-to-memory. If you want to create aligned memory with `new` in C++17 you can write:

```
weight = new (std::align_val_t(32)) float[HKP_size * acc_size];
```

Comment: unfortunately, this still doesn't fix my issue. Does your code run without exceptions?

Comment: I honestly did not run this, just found the (to me) most obvious mistake. I recommend reducing your code to the simplest code which reproduces the problem. I suspect that at some point you read beyond array boundaries.

Comment: The code i shared is already greatly reduced, but I can continue. However, i don't think i read beyond array boundaries, as i already checked multiple times. The problem has to do with the way i use the avx instructions/registers, as this is what i am not familiar with.

Comment: @Nonlinear: Find which instruction still faults, using a debugger.  Find out which array it's accessing; that's the one that's still insufficiently aligned.  (Or you're accessing it starting at an offset that's not a multiple of the vector width).  A debug build should let you debug the C++ source without looking at the asm much or at all.  Aligned allocations, and compiling with `-std=gnu++17` or later, is a necessary step, but not sufficient if you have other bugs.